# How to debug this controller in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the HTML as follows:

```
                    <div class="col-md-4">{{ctrl.serviceInstance.additionalPorts}}<span
                            ng-if="ctrl.serviceInstanceOfActiveDeployment != null && !ctrl.compareArrays(ctrl.serviceInstanceOfActiveDeployment.additionalPorts,ctrl.serviceInstance.additionalPorts)"
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert alert-icon"
                            uib-tooltip-html="'Active Deployment has a different set of Additional Ports.'"></span>
                    </div>
```

And, the controller is defined as:

```
function _compareArrays(arr1,arr2){
    if (arr1 === null && arr2 === null)
        return true;
    if (arr1 != null && arr2 != null) {
        arr1.sort();
        arr2.sort();
        var result = arr1.length == arr2.length && arr1.every(function(element, index) {
                return element === arr2[index];
            });
        return result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want to check what values are being passed to the variables `arr1` & `arr2`. The code is getting minified in my browser, and I am unable to access the variables directly in the console of the browser. How can I access these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [ng-inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj?hl=en) to get the values of the controller scope and it gives a very good tree represtational view of the same.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function _compareArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  console.log('this is arr1' + arr1);
  console.log('this is arr2' + arr2);
  if (arr1 === null && arr2 === null)
    return true;
  if (arr1 != null && arr2 != null) {
    arr1.sort();
    arr2.sort();
    var result = arr1.length == arr2.length && arr1.every(function(element, index) {
      return element === arr2[index];
    });
    return result;
  }
  return false;
}
```

should be done with console.log statements as written above